# How to loop through xml resource to set ID programatically

Tags: android, xml, loops, kotlin

Does somebody here have experienced how to loop through xml resource file to get ID from there and set it to view Programmaticaly.

i have already tried to research but nothing seems close to my problem

```
private fun createImageView(){

    newView = ImageView(this)
    coordinatorLayout.addView(newView)
    newView.id = NewViewAssignedID     //This is how i set up ID rightnow
    newView.layoutParams.height = 400
    newView.layoutParams.width = 400
    newView.x = 520F
    newView.y = 100F
    newView.setImageResource(getResources().
    getIdentifier(ImageToUse,"drawable","com.example.tema"))
    newView.setOnTouchListener(listener)
    btn_ScaleOk.isVisible = true
    mScaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, ScaleListener())
    CanScaleNow = true
    NewViewAssignedID++
    Toast.makeText(this,newView.id.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
```

Need help

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item name="one" type="id"/>
<item name="two" type="id"/>
<item name="three" type="id"/>
<item name="four" type="id"/>

</resources>

Comment: this is my resource file

Comment: Please add that in the question, not in the comment section.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do? Those `R.id` names only really exist during design and coding. At runtime, they're just numbers. Why don't you just keep using that incrementing counter? Alternatively, why don't you just define those `ImageView`s in a layout, and set those IDs directly on them?

Comment: Btw, for general Android programming questions, the correct tag is [android]. The [android-studio] tag is for questions specifically about the IDE.

Comment: Thanks sir. just wondering if its possible to do it that way. well  using increment id is not a bad idea at all. Thanks for the response sir :)))))